# How to use existing comparators in Kotlin

Tags: java, lambda, kotlin, comparison, comparator

```
@Suppress("UNCHECKED_CAST")
val comp = Integer::compare as Comparator<Int>
```

Results in:

```
java.lang.ClassCastException:
org.organicdesign.fp.xform.TransformableTest$testToImSortedSet$comp$1
cannot be cast to java.util.Comparator
```

I can do this:

```
val comp = Comparator{ a:Int, b:Int -> Integer.compare(a, b) }
```

or

```
val comp = Comparator{ a:Int, b:Int -> a.compareTo(b) }
```

But is there a better way?  I feel like I shouldn't have to create a new wrapper function for this.

Comment: What's the use case? You might get away with passing method itself as an argument, unless you explicitly need a Comparator instance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a [function reference](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/reflection.html#function-references), and instead of

```
val comp = Comparator { a: Int, b: Int -> Integer.compare(a, b) }
```

... just write this:

```
val comp = Comparator(Integer::compare)
```

Comment: That's briefer, thank you, but does it compile to a cast, or does it still add a wrapper around an existing function that should already be compatible with Comparator?

Comment: There's no such thing as a "function that is compatible with Comparator."  A function is a function, a `Comparator` is an object.  There's no alternative to a wrapper.

Comment: @LouisWasserman So, if you have a Kotlin method that takes "a comparator" would you recommend declaring it as `(A, A) -> Int` instead of `Comparator<in A>`?  The latter seems more specific and that appeals to me on some level.  I don't want any old 2-argument-of-same-type function that returns an int.  I want an actual comparator, no?  In practice, it may not be a big difference, I don't know.

Comment: No.  They'll boil down to exactly the same thing, and have an object in both cases.

Comment: @LouisWasserman Kotlin allows passing an apparently unwrapped `Integer::compare` to a function with a parameter declared `(A, A) -> Int` and *rejects* `Comparator(Integer::compare)`.  With the signature Comparator<in A> it allows/rejects the opposite.  Weird.

Comment: `Integer::compare` is not "unwrapped."  It silently creates a wrapper.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/172912/discussion-between-glenpeterson-and-louis-wasserman).

Comment: There's nothing weird about that: ["Function references belong to one of the `KFunction<out R>` subtypes, depending on the parameter count"](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/reflection.html#function-references). `Comparator` and `KFunction2` are different types. That's it.

Comment: How to use `compareBy` here?